# jQuery UI: Cannot drag an element in a z-index stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am developing an app with many draggable and droppable elements.  They all work except in this one case:

This should be draggable:

```
<div id="8093244595324" class="insertion ui-draggable" style="z-index: 4; position: relative;">
    Test Accou...<br />0.330H
</div>
```

And here's some surrounding HTML.

```
<div class="paginationPageMargin" style="">
    <div id="8195443196587" class="paginationPage" style="">
        <div id="8290907158934" class="oneEighthPageLayer" style=""></div>
        <div id="8222242963571" class="oneSixthPageLayer" style=""></div>
        <div id="8460851026264" class="oneThirdPageLayer" style="">
            <div id="8072616373566" style="height: 33%;">
                <div id="8686623363113" class="oneThird insertionBlock" value="&nbsp;" style="">
                    <div id="8093244595324" class="insertion ui-draggable" style="z-index: 4; position: relative;">
                        Test Accou...<br />0.330H
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="8810410276771" style="height: 33%;">
                <div id="8605800682859" class="oneThird insertionBlock" value="&nbsp;"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="8509644301764" style="height: 33%;">
                <div id="8708665901661" class="oneThird insertionBlock" value="&nbsp;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>Page 1
</div>
```

Note that there's some z-index stuff going on here.  The draggable element itself is index 4.  Each page layer div also has a z-index:

```
.oneThirdPageLayer {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
}

.oneSixthPageLayer {
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
}

.oneEighthPageLayer {
    z-index: 3;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I'm not sure if the z-index stuff is relevant or not, as I've taken care to ensure that the element that I'm binding draggable to is on the top of the stack.

Here's the draggable binding:

```
$('.insertion').draggable({
    start: handleDragStart
});
```

And handleDragStart:

```
function handleDragStart( event, ui ) {
    var $insertion = ui.helper,
        insertion = getInsertion($insertion.attr('id'));

    // This insertion is in the air now... it has no blocks
    insertion.insertionBlocks = [];
}
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Z-Index should not directly influence if a element is "draggable", only it's position in Z axis (if elements appear in front or behind other elements)

Comment: Unless my mousedown event isn't reaching it

Comment: I just appended a clone(true,true) of that element elsewhere, and my mousedown on the clone triggered the drag to start on the original element.  I think mousedown is not reaching it.

Comment: .remove() 'ing the z-index layers that are initially on top of it temporarily resolved the issue - but that is not a solution.  I do not understand why doing a .css('z-index','100'), which would be a solution, does not work.

Comment: i strongly believe this has to do with the z-index context.  A parent element has position: absolute.  But setting the draggable element position to relative does not resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all z-index values except for the insertions.